# Gradle Java library including custom Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I would like to create a Java library with Gradle as a building tool. I want to create custom Gradle plugin and this plugin should be availble for the libary user once it's added to project dependencies. The whole library JAR artifact should consist of Java project (let's say it's some sort of framework) and Gradle plugin (as a standalone project). Do you have any tips for me, how to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

I wonder:

1. What should be the project file structure? Should I crate Gradle module that is wrapping other 2 Gradle modules (framework and Gradle plugin)?
2. How should I build the JAR artifact? Should all buil configuration be included in root Gradle module? What should be this configuration?
3. How user of the library will be able to use the plugin in his project?

I haven't tried to do it yet. I only did some research about developing Gradle plugin as a standalone project and about multimodule Gradle projects.